# QGIS Cloud problem when uploading Hartebeesthoek94 projections

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-cloud

I get the following error message when I am trying to upload (datasets all in Hartebeesthoek94 projection).

```
Failed to create SRS record on database: new row for relation "spatial_ref_sys" violates check constraint "spatial_ref_sys_srid_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (520000874, EPSG, 520000874, PROJCS["Hartebeesthoek94_Lo29_(E-N)",GEOGCS["Hartebeesthoek94",D..., +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=29 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +...).


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users/phili/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 1207, in upload_data
    self.data_upload.upload(self.db_connections.db(
  File "C:\Users/phili/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgiscloud\data_upload.py", line 284, in upload
    raise RuntimeError(str(messages))
RuntimeError: Failed to create SRS record on database: new row for relation "spatial_ref_sys" violates check constraint "spatial_ref_sys_srid_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (520000874, EPSG, 520000874, PROJCS["Hartebeesthoek94_Lo29_(E-N)",GEOGCS["Hartebeesthoek94",D..., +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=29 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +...).
```

Comment: Can you share one of your files?

Comment: There isn't an EPSG code 520000874. Perhaps you want [epsg:2053](https://epsg.org/crs_2053/Hartebeesthoek94-Lo29.html)

Answer (score 0):

The PostGIS internal `spatial_ref_sys` check constraint doesn't allow EPSG Codes bigger then `998999`. In your case you try to add a refsys with an EPSG Code of `520000874`. This is not allowed.

```
RuntimeError: Failed to create SRS record on database: 
new row for relation "spatial_ref_sys" violates check constraint spatial_ref_sys_srid_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (520000874, EPSG, 520000874, PROJCS["Hartebeesthoek94_Lo29_(E-N)" ...
```

Comment: Whilst codes for current EPSG spatial objects (such as CRS) are no bigger than 5 digits, deprecated codes can be much longer such as EPSG:61486405, so check constraint may be too harsh